# Is LatLng inside a polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a typical polygon set on a google map with some latLng's:

```
var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),
  ]
});
bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
```

these are the Bermuda Triangle coords from google's documentation. I also have some random coords, saaay:

```
var coord1 = new new google.maps.LatLng(26.194876675795218,-69.8291015625)
var coord2 = new new google.maps.LatLng(33.194876675795218,-63.8291015625)
```

the first one happens to be inside the triangle, and the second one outside. These are just examples though, what I need is a way to find out, if a provided coordinate (not just one of these 2, any coordinte) is inside or outside the polygon (also, not always the Bermuda Triangle, not even a triangle - the polygons can have any number of latLng's). I've looked through the Google Maps API documentation, but I couldn't find any function that provides 
an answer to this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly) method.

> containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon)   boolean     Computes whether the given point lies inside the specified polygon.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdsgr1pd/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function checkInPolygon(marker, polygon) {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var html = "";
  if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(marker.getPosition(), polygon)) {
    html = "inside polygon";
  } else {
    html = "outside polygon";
  }
  infowindow.setContent(html);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
}

var map;
var coord1 = new google.maps.LatLng(26.194876675795218, -69.8291015625);
var coord2 = new google.maps.LatLng(33.194876675795218, -63.8291015625);

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < bermudaTriangle.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(bermudaTriangle.getPath().getAt(i));
  }
  bounds.extend(coord1);
  bounds.extend(coord2);
  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: coord1
  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: coord2,
  });
  map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
  map.setZoom(3);
  checkInPolygon(marker1, bermudaTriangle);
  checkInPolygon(marker2, bermudaTriangle);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),
  ]
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the Google Maps API doesn't have any methods specifically for this, then you'll need to find or write your own.  It's a common problem in computer graphics, and if you Google "polygon hit testing" you'll find a wealth of information.  [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test) looks reasonably comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

In V3 API there is google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation static method.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly

So you just have to pass the polygon and the point you want to check if it is or not inside the polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at wikipedia [Point in polygon page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon). There are couple of ways to determine if the point is inside the polygon. One of them is ray casting algorithm. [This page](http://hammerspace.co.uk/2011/10/google-maps-api-points-in-polygons) has some examples on how to implement that in google maps.