# checking if a point is inside of a polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, drawing

I'm trying to use this:
[JS- Check if Point Inside A Polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521982/js-check-if-point-inside-a-polygon)

in order to determine whether a point lies within a user-drawn polygon on a google map (which is embedded in a Salesforce visualforce page). However, it always returns false, even when the point clearly lies within the polygon that I have drawn.

When I tested it with the commented-out, hardcoded polygon coordinates, it works correctly.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my javascript/visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="ControllerJSGeoMaps" docType="html-5.0">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=drawing"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<apex:includeScript value="https://c.na16.visual.force.com/resource/1466633623000/connection"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/soap/ajax/24.0/apex.js"></script> 


<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function() {

sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
         var myOptions = {
             zoom: 10,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
             mapTypeControl: true,
             scrollwheel: false,
             center:{lat: 33.9037779, lng: -118.3892208}
         }
         var map;

 var polygonArray = [];
        //create map
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        map.setTilt(45); 
 //Draw polygon
initMap();
      function initMap() {

        var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
          drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
          drawingControl: true,
          drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: ['polygon']
          }

        });
        drawingManager.setMap(map);
 google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
          for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
           var poly=polygon.getPath().b[i];
            console.log("poly point "+i+"::"+poly.toString());
            polygonArray.push(poly);
        }



        console.log("polygonArray::"+polygonArray);
polyPrint();


});

function polyPrint(){
for (var j=0; j<polygonArray.length;j++){
var polygon = [ polygonArray[j] ];
//var polygon =  [ [33.963864308201565, -118.5040283203125],[34.02648590051866, -118.36807250976562],[33.871555787081476, -118.26507568359375],[33.80653802509606, -118.46282958984375]];
var point=[ 33.9037779, -118.3892208 ];
var hide=inside(point, polygon);
console.log("true/false::"+hide+" point::"+point+" polyArray[j]::"+polygon);
}//j

}//function

      }
      /////////////////////////
      function inside(point, vs) {
    // ray-casting algorithm based on
    // http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html

    var x = point[0], y = point[1];

    var inside = false;
    for (var i = 0, j = vs.length - 1; i < vs.length; j = i++) {
        var xi = vs[i][0], yi = vs[i][1];
        var xj = vs[j][0], yj = vs[j][1];

        var intersect = ((yi > y) != (yj > y))
            && (x < (xj - xi) * (y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi);
        if (intersect) inside = !inside;
    }

    return inside;
};

     });//readyfunction
</script>

<style>
#map {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:normal !important;
  height:800px;
  background:transparent;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div> 


</body>



</apex:page>
```

Comment: Maybe use the [google.maps.geometry library `.contains` method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is LatLng inside a polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097464/is-latlng-inside-a-polygon)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the contains method of the geometry library to check if the point is inside the polygon :

```
// point needs to be an object of type  google.maps.LatLng class 
// polygon needs to an object of type google.maps.Polygon class
function inside(point, polygon) {
   return google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, polygon)
}
```

In order to use this method you will need to include the geometry library :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=drawing,geometry"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the function incorrectly.

```
function polyPrint(){
  for (var j=0; j<polygonArray.length;j++){
    var polygon = [ polygonArray[j] ];
    //var polygon =  [ [33.963864308201565, -118.5040283203125],[34.02648590051866, -118.36807250976562],[33.871555787081476, -118.26507568359375],[33.80653802509606, -118.46282958984375]];
    var point=[ 33.9037779, -118.3892208 ];
    var hide=inside(point, polygon);
    console.log("true/false::"+hide+" point::"+point+" polyArray[j]::"+polygon);
  }//j
}//function
```

`polygonArray[j]` is a single vertex.  A polygon with a single vertex is highly unlikely to contain any points.